# How to edit the save data of newly added object before saving to database

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have a formarray where in, if i edit the value which is coming from the saved data from database as it has unique id as agentW9id so it is getting updated in that particular row, but for newly added row, as there is no unique id, how can i save the changes to that particular row on edit and show the changed values on click of save button.

I have working demo here:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-opgbqx?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts)

TS:

```
saveW9Details(item) {

        if(this.employee ) {
          if(item.agentW9id.value) {
            for(var i=0;i<this.employee.length;i++){
              if(this.employee[i].agentW9id===item.agentW9id.value){
                this.employee[i].taxId=item.taxId.value;
                this.employee[i].businessType=item.businessType.value;
                this.employee[i].signatureDate=item.signatureDate.value;
                this.employee[i].agentW9id = item.agentW9id.value;
                // updated=true;
                this.temporaryControls.push(this.employee[i])
              }
           }
          } else {

            var temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
              businessName: item.businessName[0].value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):''
            }
            if(this.employee) {
              this.employee.push(temp);
              this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
            } 
      //  this.getFormData.removeAt(item)
          }
        } else {
         console.log(item,"dsds")

            let temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
              businessName: item.businessName[0].value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):''
            };
            this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
        }

       this.getFormData.removeAt(item);


        }

}
```